# How to give Image path from Static Resource in Community using Design Attribute

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

[image]

[image]

I am trying to use Image from Static resource in Community using Design Attribute like 
`<img src="{!$Resource.DealRegChannelRedDot}"/>`

but it's not working.it is showing blank like path is not correct

```
<!-- Component -->
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="showBannerImage" type="boolean" default="" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="bannerImage" type="String" default="" access="global" />
    <div class="container">
        <aura:if isTrue = "{!v.showBannerImage}">
            <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.bannerImage}"/>
        </aura:if>
    </div
</aura:component>


<!-- Design -->
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="showBannerImage" label="Show Banner Image" />
    <design:attribute name="bannerImage" label="Banner Image" />
</design:component>
```

is there a way to achieve this using static resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already upload a image in the static resources.
setup>static resources then you can access Image like `<img src="{!'/sfsites/c/resource/'+YOUR_STATIC_RESOURCE_NAME}"/>`

as you are trying to access image using `Design property` you can use below Lightning code:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="showBannerImage" type="boolean" default="" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="bannerImage" type="String" default="" access="global" />
    <div class="container">
        <aura:if isTrue = "{!v.showBannerImage}">
            <img src="{!'/sfsites/c/resource/'+v.bannerImage}" style="width: 100%;" />
        </aura:if>
    </div
</aura:component>
```

and your Lightning Design Will look same

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="showBannerImage" label="Show Banner Image" />
    <design:attribute name="bannerImage" label="Banner Image" />
</design:component>
```

Now you just have to call your Static Resource Name in `showBannerImage` property. for example if your static resource name is `imageResource` then you just have to call this name simply in `community lightning page attribute.`

P.S. If my answer helps you to solve your problem please mark it as best answer. It will help other to find best answer.

Comment: I tried the above code that you've mentioned and it really works, but how can we use the whole ```image URL``` in Design attribute property like ```{!'/sfsites/c/resource/'+Resource_Name}```. 
Can we use like this in SFDC or we can do it with different way using Property attribute.                                                                                                                       
          And one more Question - how can i use File Upload attribute in community like where we can directly upload image from local system and upload in the Asset.